# Why to use @Query(“”) to operate Elasticsearch and report errors (org.elasticsearch.common.ParsingException: no [query] registered for [query])

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

My code

```
package com.tl666.elasticsearch.pojo;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;

import java.util.Date;

@Data
@Document(indexName = "blog", type = "blogtext")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Blog {
    private Integer id;
    private String title;//标题
    private String text;//文本内容
    private String[] images;
    private Person person;
    private Date create_time;
}
```

Operation Elasticsearch

```
package com.tl666.elasticsearch.repository;

import com.tl666.elasticsearch.pojo.Blog;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Query;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;

public interface BlogRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Blog, Integer> {
    @Query("{ \"query\": { \"match\": { \"title\": \"?0\" }}}")
    Blog findByName(String title);
}
```

The following exception occurred

```
org.elasticsearch.common.ParsingException: no [query] registered for [query]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.AbstractQueryBuilder.parseInnerQueryBuilder(AbstractQueryBuilder.java:337) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.4.jar:6.8.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.WrapperQueryBuilder.doRewrite(WrapperQueryBuilder.java:165) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.4.jar:6.8.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.AbstractQueryBuilder.rewrite(AbstractQueryBuilder.java:284) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.4.jar:6.8.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.builder.SearchSourceBuilder.rewrite(SearchSourceBuilder.java:949) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.4.jar:6.8.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.builder.SearchSourceBuilder.rewrite(SearchSourceBuilder.java:80) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.4.jar:6.8.4]
```

I am operating according to the official documentation, but the above exception occurred.

Who will help me? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `query` section. Try this instead:

```
@Query("{ \"match\": { \"title\": \"?0\" }}")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Val showed you the correct query, but you don't need a custom query for that, you can search in the title property by defining:

```
public interface BlogRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Blog, Integer> 
{
     Blog findByTitle(String title);
}
```